# Rational point inside a rational polygon

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, rational-numbers, geometric-topology

I have the following conjectures.

**Conjecture 1**:

Hypotheses:

- Let $P = (v_1, v_2, …. v_n)$ be a (convex or concave) polygon drawn on a plane.
- The lengths of the edges $(v_1, v_2)$, $(v_2, v_3)$ ... $(v_n, v_1)$ are all rational numbers.

Conclusion:

- There exists a point $x$ inside the polygon with rational coordinates such that the euclidean distances between the pairs $(x,v_1), (x,v_2), … (x,v_n)$ are all rational numbers.

**Conjecture 2**:

Hypotheses:

- Let $P = (v_1, v_2, …. v_n)$ be a (convex or concave) polygon drawn on a plane.
- The lengths of the edges $(v_1, v_2)$, $(v_2, v_3)$ ... $(v_n, v_1)$ are all rational numbers.
- The co-ordinates of the vertices $v_1, v_2, …. v_n$ are all rational numbers.

Conclusion:

- There exists a point $x$ inside the polygon with rational coordinates such that the euclidean distances between the pairs $(x,v_1), (x,v_2), … (x,v_n)$ are all rational numbers.

The above conjectures sound like a very natural topology problems. Note that the Conjecture 1 implies the Conjecture 2.

**What I know so far**:

1. The above conjectures are true for $n=3$. This follows from the following theorem.

   **Theorem**: The set of points with rational distances to the vertices of a given triangle with sides of rational length is everywhere dense.
2. Conjecture 1 is false for $n > 3$. For a proof, see Robert Kleinberg's comment on [my blogpost](https://kintali.wordpress.com/2021/10/03/prove-or-disprove-this-geometry-conjecture/).

**Questions about Conjecture 2**:

- Is it true for $n=4$ ?
- Is it true for convex polygons ?
- Is it true for convex polygon with $n=4$ ?
- Is it true for any other special cases ?
- Are there any known generalizations to higher dimensions?

**A very special case I am very interested in**:

- Let $Q = (v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4)$ be a polygon.
- The co-ordinates of the vertices $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4$ are all rational numbers.
- The lengths of the edges $(v_1, v_2)$, $(v_2, v_3)$, $(v_3, v_4)$ and $(v_4, v_1)$ are all rational numbers.
- The distance between $v_1$ and $v_3$ is rational.

**Conjecture Q1**: There exists a point $x$ with rational coordinates **inside** $Q$ such that the euclidean distances between the pairs $(x,v_1), (x,v_2), (x,v_3), (x,v_4)$ are all rational numbers.

**Conjecture Q2**: Same as Conjecture Q1 when the polygon $Q$ is convex.

Comment: Would the theorem be more impressive if you scaled distances and placed all points on a a grid in $\mathbb{Z}^2$?

Comment: I can't see that topology is involved here.

Comment: Can you clarify which are the hypotheses and which are the conclusions of your conjecture?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork There are examples of polygons with integer edge lengths with no integer point x. But a rational point x exists.

Comment: @EthanDlugie I have made edits and clarified the hypotheses and conclusions.

Comment: Could you please include the proof of the conjectures in the case $n=3$? This will help others make progress on the problem.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk I have added details for $n=3$.

Comment: D19 in Richard Guy, Unsolved Problems in Number Theory: "Is there a point all of whose distances from the corners of the unit square are rational?" I believe this problem remains unsolved. Guy gives much discussion of this & related questions, and also many references to the literature.